# React Native: "undefined is not an object" Rendering components with ListView and external dataSource

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a Container component that should render a ListView.

The ListView's dataSource needs to call an external (But local) JSON file with a list of "reservations".

The ListView should render a new "card" for each entry in the JSON file with a title.

However, I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.dataSource.title')

Below is a gist of my code ... what am I doing wrong?

https://gist.github.com/chapeljuice/316cb72432bf0d3ff90ca93349b85570

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think if you use

```
this.props.data.title
```

or

```
this.props.title
```

instead of

```
this.props.dataSource.title
```

you can get answer. because when you pass data to 'ReservationCard', data will be as props to it.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!